# SystemArgumentOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

```
namespace Cropping_Image
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var img = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Overnighter\Desktop\test.png"));
            int num = 1;
            int x1 = 0;
            var x2 = 120;
            int y1 = 0;
            var y2 = 120;

            while (x2 != img.Width)
            {
                var width = x2 - x1+1;
                var height = y2 - y1+1;

                var result = new Bitmap(width, height);

                for (var i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
                    for (var j = y1; j <= y2; j++)
                        result.SetPixel(i - x1, j - y2, img.GetPixel(i, j));

                result.Save(@"C:\Users\Overnighter\Desktop\file\"+ num +".png");
                    num++;
                    x1 += 120;
                    x2 += 120;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specification of the Error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "The parameter must be positive and less than the height.
**Parameter name: y "**
How can I fix this error?

Comment: According to the error, by making `y` positive and less than the height. Which part of that has you stuck?

Comment: By making sure `j - y2` is never negative

Comment: Use the debugger and debug your code at run time. See what the variable values are at the time of the exception and see how those values were obtained. Part of developing is learning how to debug your own code by walking through it.

Comment: `j - y2` will be negative. Did you mean `y2 - j`?

Comment: for (var i = x1; i < x2; i++) for (var j = y1; j < y2; j++) - the same result

Comment: @itsme86, I'm sorry, but I still don't get it right.There is no y variable in my code. Could you please show me my mistake?

Comment: @TimOvernighter The `SetPixel` method takes a y parameter and it's this method that's throwing the exception

Answer (score 0):

In that Piece of code:

```
result.SetPixel(**i - x1**, **j - y2**, img.GetPixel(i, j));
```

You need to be sure that **i - x1** (x parameter) and **j - y2** (y parameter) are positive,
i think that something like that should be enought to remove the exception:

```
    for (var i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
                        for (var j = y1; j <= y2; j++)
                            if((i - x1)>=0 && (j - y2)>=0)
                                 result.SetPixel(i - x1, j - y2, img.GetPixel(i, j));
```

but if you get that message you're probably soing something wrong u.u